# Method \"POST\" not allowed in Django rest framework with extra actions & ModelViewset

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to POST with extra actions in Django Rest, but am getting this error

```
{"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}
```

This is the method for POST :

```
class TemplateView(ModelViewSet):
    @action(detail=False, methods=['POST'],
                url_path=r'process_version_template/')
        def process_version_template(self, request):
    
            print("request", request)
    
            return JsonResponse({}, safe=False, status=200)
```

In my `urls.py` :

```
api_router = DefaultRouter()
api_router.register(r'template', views.TemplateView, 'template')
urlpatterns = [
    path('predefined-comments', PredefinedCommentListView.as_view(),
         name='predefined_comments'),
]

urlpatterns += api_router.urls
```

Then my endpoint am using in Postman to send data is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/financing-settings/template/process_version_template/
```

then, the body is :

```
{
    "id":1784,
    "param":"block",
    "target":315
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't need to put that trailing slash

Change

```
`url_path=r'process_version_template/'`
```

to

```
`url_path=r'process_version_template'`
```

Comment: I did that , but the error is still persisting

Comment: Hard turned `detail=True`, but now it's  `False ` what does `detail` mean ?

Comment: `detail` means whether the custom view is a Detail View or not